# php ODBC en hosting no conecta con SQL server

Tags: php, odbc, mssql

por que los drivers de este codigo no conecta a MSSQL que esta en una maquina APARTE VPS  de estados unidos? Y tengo una web en un hosting en canada en php que quiero conectar via ODBC con el VPS que esta en el otro PAIS pero cuando la pongo en el hosting no conecta con VPS y tengo el puerto abierto 1433 aun asi no entra nada ni arroja ningun resultado, este el el codigo que tengo:

```
<?php
include_once"datos.php";
    if(($dbConn = @odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server="ip_vps_en numero";",$SQLUser,$SQLPass)) == false)
        die('Error de Test revise libreria y puertos permitidos!');
$resultado = ("SELECT TOP 1 UserID FROM PS_basedatosX.dbo.mitable");
$resultd0 = odbc_exec($dbConn,$resultado);
$test = odbc_fetch_array ($resultd0);
echo "<h1><center><font color='green'>Exito al Conectar</font>, El Primer usuario registrado es:<font color='red'> ". $test['UserID']."</font></center></h1>"; 
?>
```

Alguna forma de solucionarlo?

Este drivers de ODBC lo instale en windows 7, Windows 2016 y nada no conecta.

[image: Instalacion de ODBC y apertura al PUBLICO de ODBC]

Que version de PHP debo usar por las dudas no sea que no tenga el PHP actualmente uso PhP5.6

Comment: Pudiste solucionar tu consulta, tengo el mimo problema, al parecer es incompatibilidad de los drivers. Tengo la misma versión en servidor y web, pero veo que en web está en unix y en server en windows.

Comment: No negativo nadie me ha ayudado y este post sigue en BLANCO